# Error cannot stat upon git pull

Tags: git, file, permissions

I tried to perform a git pull from a remote branch with the following command:

```
$ git pull origin branch_name
username@private_repository's password:
From ssh://private_repository/path/project
 * tag               branch_name       -> FETCH_HEAD
error: cannot stat 'path/name/of/file': Permission denied
error: cannot stat 'path/name/of/file': Permission denied
```

But I get the following error:

```
error: cannot stat 'path/name/of/file': Permission denied 
error: cannot stat 'path/name/of/file': Permission denied
```

Does anyone know what this means and what can I do about it?

Thanks

Comment: It might be because the files in local open with some application or your editor. And check the permission on local directory

Comment: For me Visual Studio(IDE) was locking file so pull was not possible.

Comment: For this it depends on where you are seeing this.  Having two of the same error message that permission denied means that there are probably two files open somewhere and the `git pull` can't overwrite them because they are open somewhere. 
This happened to me with Atom.io.  I had files open as the `dev` branch, then I checked out `master` and which was not up to date yet, someone else did the merge from `dev` to `master` and I wanted that up to date, but because I still had those files open I got the same error. 
Closing the files made it work.  Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The explanation is easy -- you have a security problem with your permissions on your git files and repositories.
You need to have permissions to pull your files from git.

If the directory permissions are 755 (rwxr-xr-x) including all parent directories, anyone can list the directory contents.

But you can't, so this usually means that the full directory path doesn't have 755 permissions. This also means that all parent directories must have +x permission.

Comment: This is not the correct answer, it is often a file permissions issue, not a security issue. 

Likely other programs are locking files that git is trying to access (IE Visual Studio, Atom, VS Code, another shell.) In Visual Studio you'll find the "Reload / Reload Solution " dialogue, selecting either of those will fix this.


See other comments for support of this (@TomBowers, @Brucelerner, and more)

Answer (score 107):

For those working with:

- IntelliJ IDEA
- Visual Studio
- Notepad++

**Closing the solution may resolve this error**. The IDE's git tools may still have hold of the file(s) in question.

Comment: Similarly, I had the same problem and the solution was to close Notepad++ which had the folder open via the "Folder as Workspace" option. It looks like most of the answers below are variations on the basic solution of closing any programs that reference the files and pulling again.

Comment: Modern IDEs need to be Git-aware!!!  (that said, make sure you are using a .gitignore that doesn't save unnecessary IDE files... :-) )

Comment: I had the same problem, with git-bash open in the background clinging to the files and preventing a branch switch.

Comment: Textpad can be added to this list too. It was the culprit for me, even though I didn't have any files from that project open in it at the time.

Comment: Same issue and resolution with PHPStorm and Atom.

Answer (score 27):

I've started using Atom and found it to be the issue. The Atom file tree needed to be refreshed and the git issue resolved.

Answer (score 16):

I've had this problem repeatedly with Atom, closing Atom solved it for me every time. Close any application using files that might be affected by the pull.

Answer (score 7):

I had a different solution to this error.  I've been using atom.io as my development tool.  I wanted to discard my latest trial work (via `git clean -df` followed by `git checkout -- .`)  When I did that there were some residual empty directories showing in the directory tree within Atom.

Those empty directories were generating `error: cannot stat 'path/name/of/directory': Permission denied` when I tried checking out an alternative branch within git. Way frustrating.

The fix was to simply click on the directories within Atom in the directory tree, where they would immediately 'poof' disappear.  Once they were gone, there were no more errors in git.

Comment: Nice we use same editor, right now I'm using atom, smartgit for ui and git shell alternately.

Comment: Weird. I also use atom and have never had this problem before today, did a normal `git pull` and got the error which led me here...quitting atom did the trick!

Comment: +1 on the weird, first time I've had this problem and I've been using the same repo for a year with Atom. I have just switched from GitKraken to SourceTree -> SourceTree+Atom seems to be the problem: if you leave atom open whilst switching branches this issue re-occurs

Answer (score 6):

I have been with the same problem, and the way that I figure out was **restart** my code editor closing all files related to the project (Atom) and my git GUI (SourceTree). After that, you can change the Branch.

Comment: You saved me on this one ! Atom blocked me from using a branch, closing it solved it

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was windows explorer who blocked de files. I restarted it with task manager (right mouse click, restart) and the issue was gone.

Comment: Same here. I simply closed all the explorer windows and command-line interfaces and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

Also the Angular CLI can block your files. So make sure you stop ng serve from running.

Answer (score 3):

My resolution was similar to most of the above:

- I closed Visual Studio Code,
- Closed any open file explorer windows,
- Made sure none of my bash/powershell windows had the directory open.

This still didn't work for me. I ended up:

- Checking out a different branch,
- Checking back in the branch I was trying to pull.

This time when I ran `git pull` it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue when I tried to switch between two branches of a project. The reason why it happened was git tried to access the files that were left open in my code editor.
I ran my editor as administrator and then switched to the other branch. It worked.
I hope it helps someone out there!

Answer (score 2):

what worked for me is to run sourcetree and visual studio in administrator mode

right click on icon(sourcetree or visual studio) and you should see an option 'Run as administrator'

[image]

Alternatively go to properties for particular application and in tab Shortcut select Advanced and tick option 'Run as administrator'

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yup, so I just got here and have an easy fix for Visual Studio users.

If you do a checkout of a branch, but haven't set Visual Studio to the focus, it will have a temporarily lock on the files.

Once you click on VS and allow it to reload the project files, you should be able to pull again...user error here

Answer (score 1):

I got this after doing a `git pull --all`

a `git pull` resolved the issue

I think the root of the issues was the fact that some branches had been deleted on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Your git environment isn't set up correctly.

Repos should be owned by user git. So user git should accept your public key.

Not sure what backend you're working with here, so the method for adding your key will vary.

Answer (score 0):

I had `npm run watch` for VueJS running in a background process which I forgot about which was causing git to block any changes when restoring from stash. So be aware of that!

Answer (score 0):

I closed Visual studio Code in which project was present, but still issue persisted : error : cannot stat, permission denied.

Then I saw grunt was running, so I closed grunt and did check out again and issue was resolved !